# "show picture placeholders" gets rechecked every time

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

Edit:  it seems like it's relatively random. If I restart the computer after unchecking, it's unchecked. But if I wait a while, it gets checked. But not always, I might open Word the first time in the day and its fine (unchecked), and then later it becomes checked. I can't figure out when it happens.

<s>Every time</s> I start Microsoft Word 2007 on Windows 10 it has "show picture placeholders" checked so it doesn't show pictures.

After I uncheck it they show up and everything is fine.

Until <s>I start Word again.</s> some time later.

Why is that happening?

Comment: Have you saved your default template with that setting turned off?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik No. But it seems like it's relatively random. If I restart the computer after unchecking, it's unchecked. But if I wait a while, it gets checked. But not always, I might open Word the first time in the day and its fine (unchecked), and then later it becomes checked. I can't figure out when it happens.